# Using env vars in a docker cmd?

Tags: docker, kubernetes

I have this line in my Dockerfile:

```
CMD ["rqworker", "--host=$REDIS_MASTER_SERVICE_HOST"]
```

REDIS_MASTER_SERVICE_HOST is set by Kubernetes, and works fine when accessed within my python app. I need to point rqworker to it, but it doesn't seem to be expanded:

```
redis.exceptions.ConnectionError: Error -2 connecting to $REDIS_MASTER_SERVICE_HOST:6379. Name or service not known.
```

How can I get docker to expand it into the actual value?

Comment: can you post a reproducer ? What shows `docker exec -it container env`?

Comment: It turns out that CMD timeout 10m rqworker --host=$REDIS_MASTER_SERVICE_HOST made it work, it was evaluated as a shell command then

Comment: You may as well add your comment as an answer (as you figured out, if you use the exec form, you don't have a shell environment with vars)

Answer (score 0):

Variable expansion is supported in kubernetes with the $(VAR) syntax.  Please see this doc:

http://docs.k8s.io/v1.0/user-guide/configuring-containers.html#environment-variables-and-variable-expansion